# Proving $f$ is Lebesgue integrable iff $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How can we prove the statement? 
$f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable. 
First, suppose $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, by definition, $f$ is measurable and nonnegative, so $f=|f|$ and $\displaystyle \int_E f \, d \mu=\int_E|f| \, d\mu$ implies that $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Second, suppose $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable, if $f$ is nonnegative, then $f=|f|$, so $f$ is Lebesgue integrable; if $f$ is negative, then how can I prove?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that $f$ has to be nonnegative to integrable? A measurable function is Lebesgue integrable iff the positive and negative parts are Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: if f is measurable and nonnegative, define int_E f du =sup I_E(s). right? what does positive and negative parts mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That $f$ is measurable and $\int |f| \,d\mu < \infty$ is the definition of Lebesgue-integrability of $f$.  (There's no need for $f$ to be non-negative.  Rather, one first defines the value of the integral for non-negative functions and then one uses that to define the Lebesgue integral of functions whose ranges may include both negative and non-negative numbers.)

That $|f|$ is Lebesgue-integrable would therefore involve the absolute value of the absolute value of $f$.  But that's the same as the absolute value of $f$.

The statement "$f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable." is not true unless there is an assumption that $f$ is measurable.  A counterexample is that $f$ is $-1/2$ plus the indicator function of a non-measurable set in a space whose total measure is $1/2$.  Then $|f|$ is integrable (and its integral is $1$) but $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: If |f| is Legesgue integrable, so |f| is measurable, can it imply that f is measurable?

Comment: That $|f|$ is measurable and $f$ is not can happen, but only if $f$ is a fairly exotic function.  For example suppose for every value of $x$, $f(x)$ is either $1$ or $-1$, and the set of values of $x$ for which $f(x)=1$ is not a measurable set.  Then $|f|$ would be measurable (since it's equal to $1$ everywhere) although $f$ is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: so how can you prove that if |f| is Legesgue integrable, then f is measurable? since f is measurable is an assumption of f is Legesgue integrable.

Comment: @Mathgoal: In general, you can't, as Michael's example in the comments shows. However, for *measurable* functions $f$, we *can* conclude that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $\lvert f\rvert$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: You probably want twice the indicator function minus one.  The indicator function *is* non-negative.

Comment: I assume  the integral equals $1/4$ and not $1$. Since $|f|$ in the answer equals $1/2$, it can be written as a product of $1/2$ and the indicator function of the set of measure $1/2$. The integral of this simple function equals $1/2\cdot 1/2=1/4$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remember the definition of $\mathcal{L}^1$ space (in the case of $\Bbb R^n$ with the borelian $\sigma$-algebra; the abstract case is similar): given $(\Bbb R^n,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n),m)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on the measurable space $(\Bbb R^n,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n))$, then 
$$
\mathcal{L}^1(\Bbb R^n,\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^n),m):=\{f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\;:\;f\;\;\mbox{is Lebesgue measurable and both}\;\int_{\Bbb R^n}f^+\,dm,\;\int_{\Bbb R^n}f^-\,dm\;\mbox{are finite}\}\;\;.
$$
Now simply observe that $f=f^+-f^-$ and $|f|=f^++f^-$.