# Definition of Lebesgue integrable function clarification

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have two clarification questions on the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

> 1. Does $f$ have to be a measurable function? Is this implied by the definition of the Lebesgue integral, or is it a presumption in the definition (like how a function is assumed to be bounded before defining the Riemann integral)
> 2. Do we say a function is Lebesgue integrable if $|f|$ is integrable? If not, is there an example of a function $f$ such that $|f|$ is Lebesgue integrable but $f$ is not?

Comment: Why do you ask this? Any text you look at on this material has the answers.

Comment: I've seen (or at least I think I have seen) contradictory/unclear definitions. For instance, the third paragraph in Hardy's answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393880/proving-f-is-lebesgue-integrable-iff-f-is-lebesgue-integrable. Why does he say "unless there is the assumption that $f$ is measurable?" In the first paragraph he explicitly says the function necessarily *has* to be measurable.

Comment: To be honest I just want clarification. I'm not sure if I have a more legitimate justification for asking this question.

Comment: For #1, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081021/lebesgue-integral-of-non-measurable-function

Comment: @user321210 In that third paragraph he's not talking about the _definition_ of integrability. It's a fact that if $f$ is measurable then $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable. And the statement "$f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable is false." Saying that statement is false is not saying anything about the definition. If you've seen a _definition_ that doesn't assume that $f$ is measurable the definition was simply wrong. But that post you cite does not contain any such definition.

Comment: The Lebesgue integral is only defined for measurable functions that are either non-negative or Lebesgue integrable. A function $f$ is said to be Lebesgue integrable if the Lebesgue integral of $|f|$ is finite.